# Energy of a particle as measured by an observer at infinity

Tags: general-relativity, energy, spacetime

I'm wondering if it is possible to make a definition for the energy of a particle as measured by an observer at infinity. I've looked through Wald for this but wasn't able to find anything - I may be looking in the wrong place.

Let $(M,g)$ be some spacetime. I'm aware that if we have a particle with some velocity $V^a$ at some point $p \in M$ it's only possible to define the energy (as measured by an observer with 4 velocity $U^a$) to be $E = U^aV_a$ when the observer is also present at $p \in M$ and in general we have no way to identify the tangent spaces at different spacetime points.

I'm wondering if it is possible to define such an energy in an asymptotically flat spacetime with an everywhere time-like Killing vector $K_a$ (normalised to 1 at infinity). In that case if we have a particle at some point in spacetime and a stationary observer at infinity (not present at the site of the particle) is it possible to "parallel transport" the energy of the particle to the observer at infinity and measure the energy there? (and of course we'd want this definition to reduce to the usual one when the particle and observer are present at the same spacetime point)

This seems to me to be intuitively plausible, i.e. I'm thinking of surface gravity calculations where we picture a string extending from infinity to a particle, then surely the observer at infinity should be able to measure the (some suitably defined) energy of the particle from the forces on this string?

Edit: After thinking about this for a while: In the Schwarzschild solution we have a conserved quantity $E = (1-\frac{2m}{r})\dot{t}$ which is conserved along geodesics, we also have the notion of a measured energy $E_{\textrm{obs.}}  = U^a V_a$ and if $V_a$ corresponds to a stationary observer we see that $E_{\textrm{obs.}} = \sqrt{1-\frac{2m}{r}}E$ so in fact at infinity these two notions are the same and so it would make sense to define the energy measured at infinity (of a particle not at infinity) to just be $E_{\textrm{obs.}}$ even though the particle with velocity $U$ may not be present at infinity. Perhaps this can be generalised to an asymptotically flat spacetime?

Comment: The energy of the particle does change along the path in non-conservative way, though. How does the formalism deal with that? I am particularly thinking about the physical meaning of the analog phenomenon in magnetism when we have to deal with induction. There the curvature of spacetime doesn't matter and parallel transport is trivial. Thanks to induction one would get a time dependent value. Is that the idea?

Comment: Yes, I suppose it is a similar idea. We also have another conserved quantity $E$ corresponding to the time-like Killing vector and in an asymptotically flat spacetime this $E$ would correspond to the energy the observer would measure if the particle was also present at infinity, so I wonder if it is possible to use this somehow.

Comment: I see... interesting idea. I have no intuition about it, but I hope someone can make an argument how it would work, or why it wouldn't, if there is a problem with it. I can certainly see the motivation.